# How to provide authentication link to signup user in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, email, firebase-authentication

I want firebase to send a link to the user to authenticate email. I don't know which link to provide in the function below, while I do not have a website to insert its URL..

```
ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings =
    ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
        // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
        // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
        .setUrl("https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234")
        // This must be true
        .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
        .setIOSBundleId("com.example.ios")
        .setAndroidPackageName(
            "com.example.android",
            true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
            12    /* minimumVersion */)
        .build();
```

It also says in the above code comment that URL must be whitelisted, how can I create the email and add it to the firebase whitelisted links?

I appreciate your kind help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve that check the official documentations

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth

Good luck,

Comment: Thanks, but the code snippet I put in this question was actually from the documentation. However, I still don't know how to construct a url appropriate to pass to **setUrl** function.I have created a random link and added it to authorized domains in the firebase authentication, and also added the same link in the dynamic links. and now I have an unknown error that the email is not sent...

Comment: I just want a link sent to the user email, and when this link is clicked the user should be authenticated, so the email can be used for that particular user in the app and added to the user info.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Answer (score 0):

Athentication -> sign-in method -> Domains treated

```
.setUrl("https://Domains treated/finishSignUp")
```

Settings -> General -> Package name

```
.setAndroidPackageName(
                        "Package name",
                        true,
                        "null")
```

Here you have st more completed:
https://droidmentor.com/password-less-email-firebase-auth/